# MFC Modfications in resources are ignored

Tags: mfc, resources, registry

When I edit a resource, typically a string, `IDC_STATIC`, or an entry in a menu, and I recompile the program and run the program the modifications are not shown. The old text, the old menu entry, is displayed.

To succeed I have to open the register-editor and delete the entry for the program. In the registry I see a long list of entries under the key workspace and this list seems to hinder the refresh.

How do I get the program to acknowledge the new layout? How do I force the program to overwrite the key workspace with the new settings.

Comment: I noticed this behavior too, but my question is, on what level do you want to solve this issue ? On application level you only need to code to delete the proper registry entry. At the project level, you need to call pre or post build event, something like that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2019

Comment: All sounds odd to me ...

Comment: I really have my doubts about it not working for IDC_STATIC, but I could believe for the others. Are you using the BCG derived menus and toolbars? They save their settings to the registry...at least they did with 0.8 which we are way past in 2021. Do you have a menu option in your application to reset the menus/toolbars?

Answer (score 0):

Check the dialog or WinForm uses same dialog ID(IDD_XXX).

If you're editing IDD_XXXB in resource editor, but dialog or WinForm's class is using IDD_XXXA. Then your issue is explained.